# Get list of body classes for X page?

Tags: template-tags

Is there a way to grab the list of body classes for X page? I tried:

`<?php get_body_class('home'); ?>`

but got a console error for function not defined.

Comment: Any specific reason for this. I can't find anything that does what you need.

Comment: @Pieter It's kind of a silly reason. I'm loading in content from other pages via Ajax and the body class remains the same because that part doesn't change. So I just want to replace the body classes when a certain page is loaded.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you will need to check if the current page being loaded in the specific page, most probably checking the value of `$post->ID`, and if the page being loaded in the specifc page, unset the specific body class. You can change a body class. You have to unset it and set a new body class if needed

Comment: If you get "function not defined" I bet that you are trying to use that function outside WordPress. Can you post the code for the ajax request, both server and client-side?